# Word Interop in ASP.Net site failing *sometimes*

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-word, interop

I know this is a bad idea, but I just inherited this application and am in the process of rewriting the whole thing to use the OpenXML approach.  But that is several months away from being complete and I have a bug happening now that I need to resolve.  Please don't answer with just "that's a bad idea..." as that is not helpful.

OK, I've narrowed the problem down to the line trying to open a Word .dot file via Interop.  The weird thing is that it fails only sometimes but the exact same code opening the exact same document works fine the rest of the time.  The line is executed and then just hangs there.  I added a line of logging code immediately after it and that line is never hit.  This happens only in production (of course) and only in one situation.

Any ideas of where to look?

Comment: You should discontinue using Office Interop in an ASP.NET environment. [Microsoft recommends against it](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757), largely for the reasons you just ran into. Instead, you should use a library capable of manipulating Open Office XML Document (.docx) files natively. You can say "this isn't helpful" but you'd be shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: Please read the question - I **know** it's not a good idea.  I just inherited this application and I'm working on moving to using Open XML, but that is a few months away (it's a large application), and I have an immediate bug I need to resolve that can't wait.  This has worked for 5+ years and now only fails intermittently.

Comment: What's the *one* situation where the problem occurs?

Comment: One particular .dot file.  But, replacing the bad one by copying in a .dot that works and verifying that security on the file and path is correct does not work.

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: I know it's a bad idea.  Read the question.  I have no choice right now.  Moving to OpenXML is a 4-6 month rewrite of this application

Answer (score 1):

This has been resolved.  Honestly, I'm still not sure what the issue is, except that it was not a code problem.  Some type of corruption somewhere was causing the issue.  Creating a whole new branch of files (including the problematic .dot) and a new set of database entries to cover that branch fixed the issue.  This was kind of the nuclear option but it did not require any code changes so the code was not the problem.

Lesson learned: definitely need to get to the Open XML stack ASAP!

Comment: You might have been better off ignoring this problem and instead spending the time to get to OpenXML!

Comment: I can't exactly tell all 15,000+ Spanish-speaking users to wait a few months before they can do their jobs while I convert to OpenXML...

Comment: You're very lucky that you found a "fix" for this. Hopefully, it won't break anything that used to work. That can happen when you use Office Interop in a way that doesn't make any sense. My point is, if the application is so important, you'd better increase the priority of converting it (maybe in parts), before you find an Interop problem that sucks up all the time you should be spending on solving the real problem - the marvel is that it works at all.